# Depth issues with GtkGLArea

Tags: opengl, gtk

I'm working on a Golang GTK3 OpenGL app and I'm running into issues with the depth buffer. If I compile go-gl's [cube example](https://github.com/go-gl/example/tree/master/gl41core-cube), it works fine. However, the same example, modified to replace GLFW with GTK ([source](https://gist.github.com/firelizzard18/1c891f48ddd59a1a5dd0d8153fbaa7e9)), shows depth artifacts. 100% of the OpenGL code is copy and pasted, except where I added a debug callback. The only thing that's different is GTK vs GLFW and code organization.

I have never done much with OpenGL and this has me totally stumped.

[Video (Imgur)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMWF6.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, by default GtkGLArea does not have a depth buffer. So this issue can be fixed with:

```golang
glarea.SetHasDepthBuffer(true)
```

Or in C

```c
gtk_gl_area_set_has_depth_buffer(glarea, TRUE);
```

Comment: OMG, I've been porting a GTK2 gtkglarea application to GTK3 (with the built-in GtkGLArea), and this had me stumped for a week.

Comment: Yeah, this was an extremely annoying problem to debug. IIRC I took one of their demos and converted it line by line into my code until it broke.